# How can i do flutter autofocus but keyboard dismiss

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

Whenever the page opens, I want the cursor to appear, but I don't want a keyboard. Does anyone know how I can do it?

```
TextField(
  textCapitalization:TextCapitalization.sentences,
  controller: _textEditingController,
  autofocus: true
)
```

Comment: In the context of a mobile app, this is a bit of a catch-22. The appearance of a blinking cursor means the text field is accepting input, but if the keyboard doesn't appear then there is no way to provide input. That situation strikes me as a very easy source of UI confusion on the part of the user. A better way to indicate that a text field is editable would be a descriptive hint text.

Comment: I want it just like whatsapp. There is a cursor on the whatsapp page, but the keyboard is closed

Comment: With the knowledge that I still think this is bad UX design, I would suggest putting a timer for a second and a half or so that toggles the hint text of the `TextField` to be either a pipe character "|" or empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SystemChannels` to get access to the channel that exposes a system text input control. Call `TextInput.hide` method on it to hide a keyboard once the `TextField` is built.

A straightforward example of doing this is:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(), () => SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide'));

  return Scaffold(
    body: TextField(
      autofocus: true,
    ),
  );
}
```

This may help if you don't like an idea of using `Future` here:
[Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)