# How can I hide keyboard jsut once in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a "barcoder" text field on flutter. After the page opened which is the barcoder belong,

I need to autofocus on TextField. But on the first opening, I want to hide the keyboard. And then if the user focuses on TextField The keyboard can appear.

How can I achieve this? I already try

```
class FirstDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool consumeKeyboardToken() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and it didn't work.

Here is my code

```
Card(
    elevation: 1,
    child: TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      focusNode: textFieldFocusNode,
      onEditingComplete: () {
        print('Barcode: ${textController.text}');
        buttonFocusNode.requestFocus();
        events!(context);
        if (textController.text.isNotEmpty) {
          _audioCache.play('success.mp3');
        }
      },
      controller: textController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.qr_code),
          hintText: 'Barcode',
          focusColor: Palette.asBlue,
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: why do you want to auto focus and defocus

Comment: Here is your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383936/how-can-i-do-flutter-autofocus-but-keyboard-dismiss/60392327#60392327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it goes to the next screen, you can use this in the initState of that widget.

```
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 Future.delayed(
   Duration(),
   () => SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide'),
  );
 }
```

if it didn't work click the link that i provided in the comments.